# How to make a post and get web service with no relational nested object

Tags: express, mongoose

this is my schema "Client":

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const clientSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  cuil: String,
  phone: Number,
  adress: {
    street: String,
    streetNumber: Number,
    RoofNumber: String,
    flat: Number
  }
});

mongoose.model("clients", clienteSchema);
```

And that's my post and get in clientsController:

```js
app.get("/api/clients", async (req, res) => {
  console.info("Obtaining clients");
  Client = await Client.find().populate(client, { path: "adresses" }, function(err, clients) {
    res.send(clients);
  });
});

app.post("/api/clients", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, cuil, phone, address } = req.body;

  const client = new Client({
    name,
    email,
    cuil,
    phone,
    address: new Address({
      street: { type: String },
      StreetNumber: { type: Number },
      RoofNumber: { type: String },
      flat: { type: Number }
    }),
    type: Object
  });

  try {
    let newClient = await client.save();

    res.status(201).send(newClient);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === "MongoError") {
      res.status(409).send(err.message);
    }

    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please provide additional details

Comment: I want to save a client on postman and see the address inside Object Client. For example instead see:  "client": {    "address": "3u19020320320230"} , can see:   "client": {"address":{ "id": "3u19020320320230", "street": "manhattan street", "StreetNumber": 456, "RoofNumber": "4", "flat": 0   } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct your client in your post route like this:

```js
const client = new Client({
  name,
  email,
  cuil,
  phone,
  address: {
    street: address.street,
    streetNumber: address.streetNumber,
    RoofNumber: address.RoofNumber,
    flat: address.flat
  }
});
```

Note: field names in address may be different depending on how is your req.body.address is.

I assume your req.body is like this:

```
{
  name : "Name",
  email: "abc@def.net",
  cuil: "cuil",
  phone: 1234567,
  address: {
    street: "street name",
    streetNumber: 10,
    RoofNumber: "roof number",
    flat: 12
  }
}
```